# Software for NFC based login

Tags: gratis, authentication, login, nfc

I am trying to set up an Android or Windows tablet that kids at an event can use to leave comments. This is for a non profit event so I am not looking for paid solutions because there is no budget.

This is what I would like to accomplish:

- a person taps an NFC tag on a reader
- a text input form comes up
- the text is saved along with the information contained on the NFC tag.

It can be either a desktop or web application or a plugin for some CMS

It would be great for WOW factor if there was a "Hello, "string saved on the NFC tag", leave a comment" prompt after tapping